# Finding resources for tailoring a home workout automagically

Tags: home-exercise, app, personal-training

I am lean and have some basic equipment at home (barbells, floor mat, elastic band) and would like to develop some sort of routine. Before the pandemic, I used to go to the gym and had some rotation going, but have been unable to do it from home ever since I started avoiding crowded places.

So here is what I'm looking for:

- A resource (App?) capable of taking some basic information (weight, height, BMI, age), available equipment (barbells, elastic band), time (2-3 workouts/week), and goals (muscle build) to design some workout plans for me. I understand that these are approximations, and absolutely do not replace a PT;
- I'm particularly looking at Apps as it is something that works well for me. I enjoy keeping track of my progress, and the gamification of workout works well;
- I would like to avoid simple collections of individual exercises, as it becomes problematic for me to design an all-round full body workout (LPP);

I'm hoping I can get some pointers as to where to learn more. A simple google search gives plenty of results and apps, including articles from newspapers, but it is hard to have an unbiased view. I previously used Jefit but found it difficult to find a workout that would meet my available equipment at home. I like the personalization capability of Freeletics, but am doubtful at paying so much money for a subscription without a free trial of the full app.

Comment: Just to sort this out, are you looking exclusively for an app, or resources in general? It may seem like a weird question, but the reason I ask is that if it's specifically an app you're after, then this question fits better at the Software Recommendations site rather than here, as we don't really do product recommendations on this site.

Comment: Good point, yes, I am looking for an app or website tool. This question perhaps is better suited there then - though I'm afraid the community here would have much more experience with this. But I understand, should I then close my question?

Comment: It's one of those edge cases. Because I agree, this is where you're most likely to get a nice answer. I've migrated some questions to the SoftwareRec site a few times, and checked back on them a few days later to find that they don't really get any results. I'll leave it for now and consult the other moderators.

Comment: I think fitness apps should be allowed to be asked on this site if it's in the context of "I'm looking for this specific type of feature(s). Does anyone know about an app that can provide it?", like @Sos asked.

Comment: It seems I haven't had much luck with an answer though, and even got a downvote :(

Comment: I went to edit your post and learned that "automagically" is actually a word. Neat.

Comment: I'm a moderator on Software Recommendations SE.  I can only speak for myself, but I have no problem if you want to cross-post there.  I realize cross-posting is often frowned upon, but the goal is to help people find good answers, so let's turn those frowns upside down! :)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite fitness app is called [Fitbod](https://fitbod.me/). It does cost money, but it is very much worth it.  I think it has all the features you are looking for.  I've been using it for about 4-ish years and love it.  I've had the most success with this app versus others.

I think the website does a poor job listing all of the features that could sell it better.

Here are some main features:

- Auto-generate workouts based on your settings. You can also modify any workout, replace an exercise if you don't want to do it/don't like it based on that same muscle group.
- Gym profiles: You can create separate gym profiles.  One for home, one for your main gym, a visiting gym, etc.
- You can select a bodyweight-only workout if you don't have any equipment
- Workout settings:

  - Fitness goal (Bodybuilding, strength-training, muscle tone, general fitness, powerlifting, Olympic weightlifting
  - Fitness experience (beginner, intermediate, advanced)
  - Timed Intervals
  - Circuits & Supersets
  - warm-up sets
  - workout duration
  - exclude workouts you don't like/can't do
  - Training splits (fresh muscle groups, upper/lower split, full-body, push/pull/lower split)
- Gifs and instructions for every exercise, that can be downloaded to reduce cellular data
- Muscle group recovery percentage. Once you've worked out a muscle group, it will tell you how recovered it is, and won't select it for your next workout.  If you add an exercise with that muscle group, it will give you a light exercise.
- Keeps a log of all of your workouts
- Can link to Strava and Apple health (and probably others). It takes workouts from these apps into account for muscle group recovery percentage.

Comment: This is excellent, I've installed it yesterday and will be giving it a try. I couldn't find how to link to other Apps but will be exploring it regardless. Many thanks for sharing!

Comment: Go to your gym settings (three-dot menu at the top right or click the profile), then on the top right, select the three-dot menu, then select "View App Settings", and it should give you a small list of "Connected Apps" about halfway down.  It used to be a little better to get to the app menu but it's at least still there :)